# When was the din of Arba Kosot created?

Tags: history, passover-seder-hagada, four-cups-wine

The earliest source I found for the four cups in the Seder is the [first Mishna in Pesachim 10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Pesachim.10?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi):

> On the eve of Pesah close to minhah one may not eat until nightfall. Even the poorest person in Israel must not eat [on the night of Pesah] until he reclines. **And they should give him not less than four cups** [of wine], and even from the charity plate.

The four cups were set up by the sages. Is there any source that this din was pre-Second Temple-destruction or was it only set up during the late-Tannaim period?

Comment: There are very few sources available between Tanakh and the Mishna. Asking for something from that time period is quite the limitation.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't need something specific from that time period, just a source that says that it was set up in a certain time period.

Comment: Not that much better. Good luck

Comment: Are you interested in the *law* of drinking 4 cups or in the *fact* of drinking 4 cups? The latter was most likely a precursor to the former.

Comment: @magicker72 I want to know if the custom (whether already an official law or not) was the common custom before the destruction of the Temple.